# Open a Serial Port using the Device Name in Java

Tags: serial-port

Is it possible to open a serial port using the device name instead of to open it using something like "COMX" (where X is a number)?

Comment: What do you mean by device name?  I'm assuming you're on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is not possible. We cannot open ports based off device name. I have searched a lot on this... but dont quote me on it. I guess other serial comm libraries (like SMSLib or RXTX) might be able to, though again, I dont know for sure.